# Camel, copying big file on smb gives null as file:size

Tags: apache-camel, smb

I'm copying file using smb well, but if the file is bigger (500MB-3.5GB) the log of ${header.CamelFileLength} and ${file:size} gives null.
I've written a filter to test it before consume:

```
@Override
public boolean accept(GenericFile<T> gf)
```

and it seems the gf.getFileLength() results a negative value.

Any advice to get correct result?

Thanks in advance.

Camel v2.20.1
camel-jcifs v2.18.0
jcifs v1.3.17

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is an `int` value and if the number is bigger than 2^15-1 you will get a negative number.
If this is the case what you need to do is just change it to `long` by doing the follow:

`long l = (gf.getFileLength() & 0xFFFFFFFFL);` 
and you will get the positive number.

Comment: What is the HEX value of `getFileLength()`?

Comment: A good result is 144003264 0x89550c0 (real 137MB, 144003264B), and wrong one is -1898159909 0xffffffff8edc60db (real 2.23GB, 2396807387B). But the main concern is "why the header.CamelFileLength and file:size is empty?" not my trying to do a workaround...

Comment: Did you try to use different smb client?

Comment: Didn't. Unfortunately, I cannot know how to check it? Could you send me some details? Thanks. My linux knowledge is very limited, moreover, this is a PCI-zone machine which I do not have direct access.

Comment: If you cannot replace the jCIFS it could be a problem.
So i think you just need to debug it if you can, set a break points where the code change this parameter in your scope. maybe if the number is negative the inner code does not set this parameters.

Comment: I'm using the latest jar.s. Where and which jcifs should I replace? And where from? So, I should get the source of camel-jcifs and jcifs, try to build it along with my code and plus debug info? I'm a "user" not an "educated open-source" developer. But if this is the only answer, I may try it. Thanks.